# Whats the point of the comma in Console.WriteLine outside of quotation marks

Tags: c#

One thing i noticed is if i write

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer to 2+3 is", 2+3)
```

It wont give an error but all it will print is "The answer to 2+3 is" without the answer to the equation outside the quotation marks.
So what even is the point of the comma in Console.WriteLine outside of quotation marks?

Comment: The 1st arg to Console.WriteLine is a [Composite Format String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string): *A composite format string consists of zero or more runs of fixed text intermixed with one or more format items* where format items are delimited by `{` and `}`.  But your composite format string **has no format items**.  In that case, according to the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#index-component), *An object that is not referenced by a format item is ignored.*

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer to 2+3 is", 2+3)
```

Is using the overload that treats the first argument as a format string and the subsequent arguments as a variable-length parameter list to replace into the format string. Because you don't have any elements in the format string into which to replace the result of 2+3, nothing is done with it. If you changed your code to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer to 2+3 is {0}", 2+3)
```

Then you would probably see what you're probably expecting to see.

Comment: I would take it a step further and try out multiple placeholders and parameters.  See what this produces: `Console.WriteLine("It was {0}, in the {1}, with a {2}.  Nicely done, {0}!", "Miss Scarlett", "Ballroom", "Dagger");`  Note that I'm using `{0}` in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

There are many overloaded method that accept different parameters. The purpose of the second parameter is to pass an object which could represent a method function such as "Concat" or the format of the string.
if you need to calculate the value your way. you need to add {0}, and then do that operation in the second argument using

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer to 2+3 is {0}", 2+3)
```

or you can user string interpolation like the following:

```
 Console.WriteLine($"The answer to 2+3 is {2 + 3}");
```

Comment: whats doing that called? is it just "old string interpolation"?

Comment: I know what's string interpolation, but i was asking whats the first example u gave called?

Comment: @Octavylon not sure it has an explicit name, but it is essentially a format string

Comment: @Octavylon - it's called a [Composite Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string).